# Center content vertically only on specific resolution

Tags: html, css

I've never encountered this necesity and I don't know how to do it. So I have a page with a footer and it doesn't stay down. Obviously I can make it stick to the bottom but this is not what I want in this case.

I will explain a bit more in-depth.
So I want to build a website. Every page should have the same header, footer, so on. On the front page the footer doesn't need to stick to the bottom because it is pushed down by the content.

But building another page with way lest then content makes the footer be in the middle of the page.

Here's a photo:
[image: click]

When the content isn't pushed down I want to center it vertically and push the footer down. How can this effect be acquired?

```css
/* reset.css */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video, button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

hr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

/*header.ejs*/

.btn-home {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.btn-home:hover {
    color: #f18a01;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.tear {
    font-size: 5rem;
}

.face-404 {
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

.vertical-center {
    margin: 0 !important;
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;  /* align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
    font: 0/0 a;         /* remove the gap between inline(-block) elements */
    background-color: #f18a01;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
.vertical-center:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
  
.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
                             /* reset the font property */
    font: 0.5rem/1 "Alegreya Sans";
    font-weight: bold !important;
  }

  .container-404 {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("img/404.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

/*home.ejs*/

.shrink {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -1rem;
    border-bottom: 3.5px solid orange !important;
    -webkit-animation: swing 1s ease;
    animation: swing 1s ease;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

.border {
    border-bottom: 3.5px solid orange !important;
}

.logo {
    width: 10rem;
}

.bg-orange {
    background-color: #F28A00;
    color: #fff;
}

.ml-1 > span {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.ml-1 > i {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.bara-mica-text {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.25px;
}

.margin-top-bot {
    margin: 0.2rem 0;
}

.margin-top-bot > span > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

.margin-top-bot > span > a:hover {
    color: #ADADAD;
}

.nav-item > a {
    transition: 0.4s;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.nav-item > a:hover {
    color: #F28A00 !important;  
}

.logos-top {
    height: 5rem;
}

.home-intro {
    background-image: url("../img/home-div-bg.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container-home {
    padding: 15rem 0rem 27.5rem 0rem;
}

.slogan-home {
    color: #F28A00;
}

.welcome-home {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    line-height: 4.5rem;
}

.btn1-home-custom {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #F28A00;
    outline: none;
    border-color: #F28A00;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 3rem;
    width: 12rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.btn2-home-custom {
    color: #F28A00;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 12rem;
}

.btn1-home-custom:hover,
.btn2-home-custom:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #212529;
    outline: none;
    border-color: #F28A00;
}

.btn:focus,.btn:active {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none;
 }

.container-home-butoane-intro {
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

.home-intro-2 {
    background-image: url("../img/home2-div-bg.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
}

.home-intro-2:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
 }

 .home-intro-2 > .row {
    padding: 4.5rem 0;
 }

 .home-intro-2 > .row > .col-md-6 > .display-4 {
     text-align: right;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding-right: 0.75rem;
     border-right: 2px solid #fff;
 }

 .home-intro-2 > .row > .col-md-6 > .lead {
    text-align: left;
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: 0.25rem;
}

.home-intro-2 > .row > .col-md-6 > i {
    margin-left: 0.75rem;
}

.home-intro-2 > .row > .col-md-6 > i > a {
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-weight: bold;
}

.home-suntem > .container > .row > .display-4 {
    padding-top: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #F28A00;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.home-cine-suntem {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.home-cine-suntem > a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: orange;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-weight: bold;
}

.home-sustinem > .container > .row > .display-4 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 2rem;
}

.home-sustinem > .container {
    background-color: #252525;
    color: #fff;
}

.home-articole > .container > .row > .display-4 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.home-articole > .container {
    background-color: #252525;
    color: #585858;
}

.home-articole > .container > .row > .col-md-3 {
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.home-articole > .container > .row > .col-md-3 > .home-articol {
    border: 2px solid #585858;
    text-align: center;
}

.home-articole > .container > .row > .col-md-3 > .home-articol > .lead {
    padding: 0 1rem;
    color: #585858;
}

.home-articole > .container > .row > .col-md-3 > .home-articol > h5 {
    padding: 1rem 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.home-articole > .container > .row {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.home-articole > .container > .row > .col-md-3 > .home-articol > a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #585858;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-weight: bold;
}

.home-articole > .container {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.home-cum-sustinem {
    text-align: center;
    color: #585858;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.home-cum-sustinem > a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #585858;
}

.home-services > .container > .row > .display-4 {
    padding-top: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #F28A00;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.home-services > .container > .row > .col-md-3 {
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.home-services > .container > .row > .col-md-3 > .home-service {
    border: 2px solid #F28A00;
    text-align: center;
}

.home-services > .container > .row > .col-md-3 > .home-service > .lead {
    padding: 0 1rem;
}

.home-services > .container > .row > .col-md-3 > .home-service > h1 {
    padding: 1rem 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.home-services > .container > .row > .col-md-3 > .home-service > a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: orange;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-weight: bold;
}

.home-services > .container {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.home-echipa > .container {
    background-color: #252525;
    color: #fff;
}

.eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display:         flex;
}

.home-echipa > .container > .row > .display-4 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2rem 0 2.5rem 0;
}

.home-echipa > .container > .row > .home-echipa-functie {
    font-size: 1.3rem; 
}

.home-echipa > .container > .row > .home-echipa-nume {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.home-echipa > .container > .row > .home-echipa-poza-persoana {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.home-echipa > .container > .row > .col-md-7 > .home-descriere-persoana {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #585858;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.home-proiecte > .container > .row > .display-4 {
    padding-top: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #F28A00;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.home-echipa > .container {
    background-color: #252525;
    color: #fff;
}

.proiecte-logos {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin: 4rem 0;
}

.container-fluid-margin {
    padding: 2rem 0;
    width: 70%;
}

.footer-div {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-footer {
    padding: 2rem 0;
}

.email, .phone {
    display: inline-block;
}

.form-group-custom {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


/*bootstrap navbar activate*/
@media (min-width: 1400px){
    .navbar-expand-custom {
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    .navbar-expand-custom .navbar-nav {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .navbar-expand-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        padding-right: .5rem;
        padding-left: .5rem;
    }
    .navbar-expand-custom .navbar-collapse {
        display: flex!important;
    }
    .navbar-expand-custom .navbar-toggler {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* responsive layout */
@media screen and (max-width: 670px) {
    .margin-top-bot .mr-5 {
        margin-right: 2rem !important;
    }
    .welcome-home {
        font-size: 3rem;
        line-height: 3rem; 
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 630px) {
    html {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .logos-top {
        height: 2.5rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .logos-top {
        height: 2rem;
    }
    .navbar-custom {
        padding: .2rem;
    }    
    .navbar-footer {
        font-size: 0.75rem;
    }
    .home-intro-2 > .row > .col-md-6 > .display-4 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .home-intro-2 > .row > .col-md-6 > .lead {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .logos-top-wrapper {
        display: block !important;
        margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
    .container-home {
        padding: 10rem 0;
    }
    .welcome-home {
        font-size: 2rem;
        line-height: 2rem; 
    }
    html {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .margin-top-bot .mr-5 {
        margin-right: 1rem !important;
    }
    .email, .phone {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

/*efect scroll*/
@-webkit-keyframes swing
{
    15%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(5px);
        transform: translateX(5px);
    }
    30%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-5px);
       transform: translateX(-5px);
    } 
    50%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(3px);
        transform: translateX(3px);
    }
    65%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px);
        transform: translateX(-3px);
    }
    80%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(2px);
        transform: translateX(2px);
    }
    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
@keyframes swing
{
    15%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(5px);
        transform: translateX(5px);
    }
    30%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-5px);
        transform: translateX(-5px);
    }
    50%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(3px);
        transform: translateX(3px);
    }
    65%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px);
        transform: translateX(-3px);
    }
    80%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(2px);
        transform: translateX(2px);
    }
    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

/*contact.html*/
.container-centru {
    padding: 2rem 0;
}

.heading-contact {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5rem;
}

.form-contact {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.textarea-contact,
.email-contact {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.btn-custom {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #F28A00;
    outline: 0;
}

.btn-custom:hover {
    background-color: #F28A00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:400,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
    <title>doc</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
            <div class="container-fluid border">
                <div class="row bg-orange">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="ml-1 margin-top-bot float-left">
                                <div class="phone">
                                    <i class="fas fa-phone ml-5"></i>
                                    <span class="ml-1 bara-mica-text">074 444 4444</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="email">
                                    <i class="fas fa-envelope ml-5"></i>
                                    <span class="ml-1 bara-mica-text">bestdavnic73@gmail.com</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mr-2 margin-top-bot float-right">
                              <span class="mr-5"><a href="#" class="mr-5">Locatie</a></span>
                              <span class="mr-5"><a href="#" class="mr-5">Despre noi</a></span>
                              <span class="mr-5"><a href="#" class="mr-5">Contact</a></span>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-custom navbar-light navbar-custom">     
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                      
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="./img/logo.jpg" class="logo"></a>
                          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item mr-2 active">
                              <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="/">Acasa <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                              <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Cine suntem?</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                                <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Cum te sustinem?</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                              <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Proiect 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                                <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Proiect 2</a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                                  <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Consultanta</a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                                <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Mediere</a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                                <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Portofoliu</a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                                  <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">FAQ</a>
                                </li>
                              <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                                  <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Contact</a>
                              </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="logos-top-wrapper">
                            <img src="./img/logos.png" class="logos-top">
                        </div>
                      </nav> 
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="container container-centru">
                <h1 class="heading-contact">Contacteaza-ne!</h1>
                <form class="form-contact">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="inputemail" class="email-contact">Email address</label>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputemail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted" style="font-size: 0.8rem;">Email-ul tau nu va fi impartasit cu nimeni!</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="textarea" class="textarea-contact">Mesaj (trebuie sa fii logat pentru a trimite mesajul)</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                                <input type="submit" value="Trimite" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block btn-login-custom">
                                <input type="submit" value="Resetează câmpurile" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block btn-reset-custom">
                        </div>                   
                </form>
            </div>              
        <footer>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-nav bg-orange navbar-footer">
          <div class="row footer-div">Conţinutul acestui material nu reprezintă în mod obligatoriu poziţia oficială a Uniunii Europene sau a Guvernului României.</div>
          <div class="row footer-div">Beneficiarul proiectului BEST DAVNIC73 SRL</div>
       </nav>
       </footer>
       </body>
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="javascript/js.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has built-in class for this purpose

You may use them on body

```
<body class="m-0 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between h-100">
```

it resets margins to 0 , turn it into a flex box, set direction to column , sets vertical alignement to space-between and sets height to 100%

You can run snippet below in fullpage mode to see if its efficient for you.

```css
/* reset.css */

/* reset.css */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video, button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

hr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}


/*header.ejs*/

.btn-home {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn-home:hover {
  color: #f18a01;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.tear {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.face-404 {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

.vertical-center {
  margin: 0 !important;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /* align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
  font: 0/0 a;
  /* remove the gap between inline(-block) elements */
  background-color: #f18a01;
  color: #fff;
}

.vertical-center:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
  /* reset the font property */
  font: 0.5rem/1 "Alegreya Sans";
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

.container-404 {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("img/404.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}


/*home.ejs*/

.shrink {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -1rem;
  border-bottom: 3.5px solid orange !important;
  -webkit-animation: swing 1s ease;
  animation: swing 1s ease;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

.border {
  border-bottom: 3.5px solid orange !important;
}

.logo {
  width: 10rem;
}

.bg-orange {
  background-color: #F28A00;
  color: #fff;
}

.ml-1>span {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.ml-1>i {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.bara-mica-text {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.25px;
}

.margin-top-bot {
  margin: 0.2rem 0;
}

.margin-top-bot>span>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.margin-top-bot>span>a:hover {
  color: #ADADAD;
}

.nav-item>a {
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.nav-item>a:hover {
  color: #F28A00 !important;
}

.logos-top {
  height: 5rem;
}

.home-intro {
  background-image: url("../img/home-div-bg.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container-home {
  padding: 15rem 0rem 27.5rem 0rem;
}

.slogan-home {
  color: #F28A00;
}

.welcome-home {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  line-height: 4.5rem;
}

.btn1-home-custom {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #F28A00;
  outline: none;
  border-color: #F28A00;
  border-radius: 30px;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 12rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn2-home-custom {
  color: #F28A00;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 12rem;
}

.btn1-home-custom:hover,.btn2-home-custom:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #212529;
  outline: none;
  border-color: #F28A00;
}

.btn:focus,.btn:active {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.container-home-butoane-intro {
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.home-intro-2 {
  background-image: url("../img/home2-div-bg.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.home-intro-2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}

.home-intro-2>.row {
  padding: 4.5rem 0;
}

.home-intro-2>.row>.col-md-6>.display-4 {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
}

.home-intro-2>.row>.col-md-6>.lead {
  text-align: left;
  width: 75%;
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
}

.home-intro-2>.row>.col-md-6>i {
  margin-left: 0.75rem;
}

.home-intro-2>.row>.col-md-6>i>a {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.home-suntem>.container>.row>.display-4 {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F28A00;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.home-cine-suntem {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.home-cine-suntem>a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.home-sustinem>.container>.row>.display-4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.home-sustinem>.container {
  background-color: #252525;
  color: #fff;
}

.home-articole>.container>.row>.display-4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.home-articole>.container {
  background-color: #252525;
  color: #585858;
}

.home-articole>.container>.row>.col-md-3 {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.home-articole>.container>.row>.col-md-3>.home-articol {
  border: 2px solid #585858;
  text-align: center;
}

.home-articole>.container>.row>.col-md-3>.home-articol>.lead {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  color: #585858;
}

.home-articole>.container>.row>.col-md-3>.home-articol>h5 {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.home-articole>.container>.row {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.home-articole>.container>.row>.col-md-3>.home-articol>a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #585858;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.home-articole>.container {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.home-cum-sustinem {
  text-align: center;
  color: #585858;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.home-cum-sustinem>a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #585858;
}

.home-services>.container>.row>.display-4 {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F28A00;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.home-services>.container>.row>.col-md-3 {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.home-services>.container>.row>.col-md-3>.home-service {
  border: 2px solid #F28A00;
  text-align: center;
}

.home-services>.container>.row>.col-md-3>.home-service>.lead {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.home-services>.container>.row>.col-md-3>.home-service>h1 {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.home-services>.container>.row>.col-md-3>.home-service>a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.home-services>.container {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.home-echipa>.container {
  background-color: #252525;
  color: #fff;
}

.eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.home-echipa>.container>.row>.display-4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2rem 0 2.5rem 0;
}

.home-echipa>.container>.row>.home-echipa-functie {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.home-echipa>.container>.row>.home-echipa-nume {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.home-echipa>.container>.row>.home-echipa-poza-persoana {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.home-echipa>.container>.row>.col-md-7>.home-descriere-persoana {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #585858;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.home-proiecte>.container>.row>.display-4 {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F28A00;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.home-echipa>.container {
  background-color: #252525;
  color: #fff;
}

.proiecte-logos {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin: 4rem 0;
}

.container-fluid-margin {
  padding: 2rem 0;
  width: 70%;
}

.footer-div {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-footer {
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.email,
.phone {
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-group-custom {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*bootstrap navbar activate*/

@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  .navbar-expand-custom {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .navbar-expand-custom .navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .navbar-expand-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: .5rem;
    padding-left: .5rem;
  }
  .navbar-expand-custom .navbar-collapse {
    display: flex!important;
  }
  .navbar-expand-custom .navbar-toggler {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* responsive layout */

@media screen and (max-width: 670px) {
  .margin-top-bot .mr-5 {
    margin-right: 2rem !important;
  }
  .welcome-home {
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 3rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 630px) {
  html {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .logos-top {
    height: 2.5rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .logos-top {
    height: 2rem;
  }
  .navbar-custom {
    padding: .2rem;
  }
  .navbar-footer {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
  }
  .home-intro-2>.row>.col-md-6>.display-4 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .home-intro-2>.row>.col-md-6>.lead {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .logos-top-wrapper {
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
  }
  .container-home {
    padding: 10rem 0;
  }
  .welcome-home {
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
  }
  html {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .margin-top-bot .mr-5 {
    margin-right: 1rem !important;
  }
  .email,
  .phone {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}


/*efect scroll*/

@-webkit-keyframes swing {
  15% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5px);
    transform: translateX(5px);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-5px);
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px);
    transform: translateX(3px);
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px);
    transform: translateX(-3px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px);
    transform: translateX(2px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes swing {
  15% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5px);
    transform: translateX(5px);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-5px);
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px);
    transform: translateX(3px);
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px);
    transform: translateX(-3px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px);
    transform: translateX(2px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}


/*contact.html*/

.container-centru {
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.heading-contact {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.form-contact {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.textarea-contact,
.email-contact {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.btn-custom {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #F28A00;
  outline: 0;
}

.btn-custom:hover {
  background-color: #F28A00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:400,800" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
  <title>doc</title>
</head>

<body class="m-0 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between h-100">
  <header>
    <div class="container-fluid border">
      <div class="row bg-orange">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="ml-1 margin-top-bot float-left">
            <div class="phone">
              <i class="fas fa-phone ml-5"></i>
              <span class="ml-1 bara-mica-text">074 444 4444</span>
            </div>
            <div class="email">
              <i class="fas fa-envelope ml-5"></i>
              <span class="ml-1 bara-mica-text">bestdavnic73@gmail.com</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mr-2 margin-top-bot float-right">
            <span class="mr-5"><a href="#" class="mr-5">Locatie</a></span>
            <span class="mr-5"><a href="#" class="mr-5">Despre noi</a></span>
            <span class="mr-5"><a href="#" class="mr-5">Contact</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
  </header>
  <div class="container container-centru">
    <h1 class="heading-contact">Contacteaza-ne!</h1>
    
  </div>
  <footer>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-nav bg-orange navbar-footer">
      <div class="row footer-div">Conţinutul acestui material nu reprezintă în mod obligatoriu poziţia oficială a Uniunii Europene sau a Guvernului României.</div>
      <div class="row footer-div">Beneficiarul proiectului BEST DAVNIC73 SRL</div>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="javascript/js.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a wrapper that contains your header, main, and footer; with

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
min-height: 100vh;
```

You'll need to remove margin and padding from the body and set a min-height of 100% on the body too.

```css
body {
 min-height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-between;
 min-height: 100vh;
 }
 header, footer {
 background: orange;
 padding: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>Content</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

```
flex-direction:col;
justify-content: space-between;
```

It'll just flow normally on tall pages that scroll and center the content on shorter pages, taking up the full page height.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I accepted the other as correct because it was using a bootstrap approach (and my page is built on bootstrap too). Your answer is correct too, anyway.